# ImageMagick percentage escapes in Windows 10

Tags: command-line, windows-10, imagemagick

I run the following in Windows 10 command line;

```
convert file.png %t-test.png
convert file.png '%t-test.png'
```

And I get the following files;

```
%t-test.png
'%t-test.png'
```

How can I have the expected `file-test.png` be properly escaped and generated?

### Update

Tried some others per @DavidPostill's suggestions;

```
>convert file.png '\%t-test.png'
convert.exe: unable to open image `'\%t-test.png'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.
convert.exe: WriteBlob Failed `'\%t-test.png'' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1630.
```

Also, both of the following result in `'%t-test.png'` being written;

```
convert file.png '%%t-test.png'
convert file.png '^%t-test.png'
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is this `convert` program you are running? What is this `%t` you are referring to?

Comment: The program is ImageMagick as tagged...

Comment: So what's the `%t`?

Comment: It's an ImageMagick percentage escape per the title...

Comment: Try adding the windows command line escape (backslash) to allow the convert escape (percent) to pass through: `convert file.png '\%t-test.png'`

Comment: Let me know if it works and I will write up a full answer.

Comment: Escaping in command is tricky. Please also try `convert file.png '%%t-test.png'` and `convert file.png '^%t-test.png'` as `%%` can also be an escaped `%1 and `^` is also used as an escape character. One of the three should work ...

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks - however these also did not work.  Updated question.

Comment: Hmm. I'm out of ideas ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have determined the following workaround, although it limits output to what variable manipulations are available in cmd rather that what could be accomplished with [ImageMagick percent escapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php).

```
FOR %a IN (*.png) DO convert "%a" "test-%~na%~xa"
```

Based on these batch file variables;

```
%~a    expands %a removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fa    expands %a to a fully qualified path name
%~da    expands %a to a drive letter only
%~pa    expands %a to a path only
%~na    expands %a to a file name only
%~xa    expands %a to a file extension only
```

[More here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/)